# pull WAN ip on LAN dd-wrt on native vlan

Tags: networking, vlan, dd-wrt

TO save wiring I currently have
DSL modem bridged to man LAN

That DSL modem can be accessed by any computer on native vlan.

Cable  modem is on VLAN2

One wire goes to the Asus n66u on port 4.    If i set click tag port 4 and check line 2 on port W i get a DHCP ip address assigned directly from the Cable ISP to WAN of the dd-wrt for example.

how can I pull a DHCP ip address from the Native VLAN (DSL MODEM) on Port 4 like i did getting an IP on VLAN 2 tagged ?

Answer (score 0):

yes it can

I have DSL bridged in LAN   switch
then in DDWRT
i tag the lan port 4 and WAN port and DD-WRT can access PPPOE  concetrator from 1 cable, the lan port4

please confirm this message.